# Javascript: history.go(-1) does not redirect me to updated previous/latest page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page with a dropdownlist, gridview, a button (with c#, asp.net).

Whenever I change the selecteditem in the ddList and click on the button my gridview is populated with the data related to the selecteditem and when I click on any cell (cells contain the data with hyperklinks to a low level page).

When this high level page loads with the  ddlselected value from a more hig level page it load the data related to the selected item but after I change the selecteditem in ddlist and click on the button it loads the new data and when I clik on the hyperlink in the cell data it redirects me to a new low level page and after that when i click on the back button (in the browser iexplorer), i am redirected to the previous page but it always loses that ddlist latest selected item and displays the old ddlist select item's data.

I am generating the breadcrumbs using hyperlinks with Javascript: `history.go(-1)`.

I believe the cache on the client is not updated when I change the ddlist selected item. but during the debugging when I check in the immediate window I see that it always updates the ddlist selecteditem.

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

thank you.

Comment: When you go back in browser history you are usually loading something the browser had in cache. Going back is not and will never be a safe way to have the most up-to-date content in your screen.

Comment: Try and set the cache control for the previous page to something draconic.

Comment: Also, consider editing your question into actual paragraphs and using formatting. It's pretty hard to follow as is. Spellchecking never hurts either.